# Sampling a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with spsample() results in error from seq.default()

Tags: r, gis, geo, r-sp

I am trying to use `spsample()` from `sp` to sample points that are within the borders of Belgium, using a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` from [GDAM](http://www.gadm.org/). This results in an error from a `seq.default()`-call.

```
be <- readRDS(gzcon(url('http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/BEL_adm0.rds')))
spsample(be, type="hexagonal", cellsize=10)
```

> Error in `seq.default(ll[1], ur[1] - dx/2, dx)` : 
>         wrong sign in 'by' argument

```
str(be)

# Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
#   ..@ data       :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  68 variables:
#   .. ..$ OBJECTID     : int 1
# [snip]
#   .. ..$ LDC          : chr ""
#   ..@ polygons   :List of 1
#   .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
#   .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 3
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
#   .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 3.37 51.36
# [snip]
```

Further attempts:

- Using the Shapefile-version from GDAM, results in the same error.
- Converting to a `SpatialPolygons`-object first, results in the same error.

---

```
packageVersion('sp')

# [1] ‘1.2.3’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cellsize` is too big.

Look at the bounding box of `be`:

```
bbox(be)
#         min      max
# x  2.555356  6.40787
# y 49.497215 51.50382
```

I don't understand *too* well what `spsample` is doing, but if you look at the result of tracing back your error, you can poke around in the code to debug:

```
spsample(be, type="hexagonal", cellsize=10)
traceback()
# 9: stop("wrong sign in 'by' argument")
# 8: seq.default(ll[1], ur[1] - dx/2, dx)
# 7: seq(ll[1], ur[1] - dx/2, dx)
# 6: genHexGrid(dx, bb[, 1], bb[, 2])
# 5: hexGrid(bb, n = n, offset = offset, cellsize = cellsize)
# 4: sample.Spatial(as(x, "Spatial"), n_tot * (1 + its * 0.1), type = type, 
#        offset = offset, ...)
# 3: .local(x, n, type, ...)
# 2: spsample(be, type = "hexagonal", cellsize = 10)
# 1: spsample(be, type = "hexagonal", cellsize = 10)
```

You can look at the code for `hexGrid` / `genHexGrid` (by typing `getAnywhere("hexGrid")` or, since you can guess the code is in the `sp` package, by entering `sp:::hexGrid` on the console), where you'll see that `cellsize` is being assigned to `dx`; that `ur` is the `max` column of `bbox(be)`; and `ll` is the `min` column of `bbox(be)`.

So the `x` sequence you're trying to create is actually:

```
x <- seq(2.555, 1.408, 10)
```

Thus this is trying to create a sequence from a higher to a lower number, incrementing by a positive number, which is impossible.

Instead, try a smaller `cellsize`:

```
spsample(be, type="hexagonal", cellsize=1)
# SpatialPoints:
#          x        y
# 2 4.205421 50.40138
# 3 5.205421 50.40138
# 4 6.205421 50.40138
# 5 3.705421 51.26741
# 6 4.705421 51.26741
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments:
# +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
# +towgs84=0,0,0
```

I was able to figure this all out by combining `traceback()` with some prudent use of `debugonce(sp:::sample.Spatial)`. Hopefully this answer serves as a useful debugging toolbox for you.